# Change picture when hovering with mouse

Tags: javascript

Good morning world! I've got another problem with my project, this time the JavaScript isn't working, I want the picture to change when I'm holding my mouse pointer over it, thanks for your patience!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css" type="text/css" />
    <title>Konst UF</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
      if (screen.width <= 699) {
        document.location = "mobile.html";
      }

      document.getElementById("Orderbutton").onclick = function () {
        location.href = "http://www.youtube.com/";
      };

      function billFunction() {
        var Bill = getElementById("BillGate");
        if (img.src.match("Bill")) {
          img.src = "bill-gates.jpg";
        } else {
          img.src = "Card.jpg";
        }
      }
    </script>
    <body>
      <p class="madeby">Made by Albin Karlsson and Oliver Jansson</p>
      <center>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="index.html"><p class="Home">Home</p></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#"><p class="Products">Products</p></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#"><p class="About">About Us</p></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </center>
      <center><p class="para1">Konst UF</p></center>
      <center>
        <img
          id="BillGate"
          src="bill-gates.jpg"
          alt="Bill Gates"
          class="Billgates"
          onmouseover="billFunction()"
        />
      </center>
      <marquee><h2>Bill GATES</h2></marquee>
      <div></div>
      <div class="sidepanels1">
        <center>
          <img class="Konstbild" src="Konst_uf_1.jpg" alt="Konst" />
        </center>
        <h2>Unknown</h2>
        <p>I have no idea haha</p>
      </div>
      <div class="sidepanels2">
        <center>
          <img class="Konstbild" src="mikrofiberduk-konst.jpg" alt="Monalisa" />
        </center>
        <center><h2>Mona Lisa</h2></center>
        <center>
          <p>Mona Lisa is a painting which was painted by Leonardo Da Vinci</p>
        </center>
      </div>
      <center>
        <button
          id="Orderbutton"
          type="button"
          onclick="location.href = 'http://www.youtube.com/';"
        >
          Order Our Products
        </button>
      </center>
    </body>
  </head>
</html>
```

That was the html code and I hope you could find the problem, if you need the css I got it too:

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
  border: grey solid 1px;
}

p.para1 {
  margin: auto;
  width: 40%;
  border: 3px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
}
div.sidepanels1 {
  border: 5px dotted green;
  background-color: grey;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 320px;
  height: 550px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
div.sidepanels2 {
  border: 5px dotted green;
  background-color: grey;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 320px;
  height: 550px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
p.iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
div.2nd {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
img.asus-logo {
  width: 1200px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
img.Billgates {
  margin-top: 30px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
img.Konstbild {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 3px solid green;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
p.madeby {
  position: fixed;
}
```

Thank you !

Comment: which image do you want to change

Comment: the **img** variable in **billfunction()** is not defined. You probably forgot to override it as the **Bill** variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your JavaScript change this

```
    function billFunction(img) {
        var Bill = document.getElementById('BillGate');
        if (img.src.match("Bill")) {
            img.src = "bill-gates.jpg";
        } else {
            img.src = "Card.jpg";
        }
    }
```

And in your HTML

```
<img id="BillGate" src="screenshot_tweet.png" alt="Bill Gates" class="Billgates" onmouseover="billFunction(this)"/>
```

Also you should comment the onclick code before, it's causing you problems.

A better solution would be to do this only with CSS. It's much easier.

```
#bill {
    background-image: url("bill-gates.jpg");
}

#bill:hover {
    background-image: url("Card.jpg");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets take a look at your `billFunction`, as there are a few problems with this function.

```
function billFunction() {
   var Bill = getElementById('BillGate');
   if (img.src.match("Bill")) {
      img.src = "bill-gates.jpg";
   } else {
      img.src = "Card.jpg";
   }
}
```

First of all, getting the element of your desire requires you to use `document.getElementById`, rather than just `getElementById`. Changing that should give you the correct element.

Next, you are setting `img.src`, but variable `img` is never defined. I assume this should be `Bill.src` instead. (Side note, I want to advise you to use `lowerCamelCase` variable names)

Last, your logic for checking which image to use looks wrong. `Bill` (capital B) can never be in `bill-gates`. Changing this logic using all lowercase should work.

You will get something along the lines of:

```
function billFunction() {
    var bill = document.getElementById('BillGate');
    if (bill.src.match("bill")) {
        bill.src = "bill-gates.jpg";
    } else {
        bill.src = "Card.jpg";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
           function billFunction() {
        var Bill = getElementById('BillGate');
        if (img.src.match("Bill")) {
            img.src = "bill-gates.jpg";
        } else {
            img.src = "Card.jpg";
        }
    }
```

Corrected One:

```
         $("img").hover(function(){
               $(this).attr("src","bill.jpg");
            },function(){
                $(this).attr("src","card.jpg")
                  });
```

Comment: This is a JQuery solution, but i think OP does not use JQuery

Comment: Then you can either add a event Listener on mouseover, with your function.You have a problem with the billfunction().